# Cannot open Android Webbrowser using Action_View

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I am trying to open the standard android webbrowser by clicking on a textview.
I defined the android:autoLink="web" in the textview and then use an onTouchListener to start a browserintent:

```
// On Touch Listener

chatText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                      // view.performClick();
                       view.onTouchEvent(event);

                       if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                           view.performClick();
                           openBrowser(chatText.getText().toString());
                       }
                return false;
            }
        });

 // Start Browser function

 public void openBrowser(String url) {
    Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (webIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        context.startActivity(webIntent);
    }
}
```

However, everytime I click a link on my textview I get the error:

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Although I do have the flags added to my newly started activity, anyone knows what I do wrong here?

I am calling the activity from a class ChatArrayAdapter which extends an ArrayAdapter, however, I pass the appropriate context to the newly started activity

Answer (score 1):

Going over your code, your chat text has some URL in it. To make things easier, Android has `Linkify` class and the `android:autoLink` XML attribute. These help to automatically highlight links and perform the standard action when you click on them. All of this is handled out of the box.

Your `chatText` is probably a `TextView`. You can use one of the two ways I mentioned like so:

In XML:
In your `chatText`'s XML add the following attribute:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

In code:

```
Linkify.addLinks(chatText,Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```